# How can I use i18n for my error pages in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need use the `I18n api` on my `public/404.html` page.

If I add to 404.html page:

```
<%= t('.page_were_looking') %>
```

I get an error message like:

```
Cannot use t('.page_were_looking') shortcut because path is not available
```

How can I use the `I18n` feature to this page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails supports multilinguality by serving up error pages with a path like `public/500.de.html`, where `de` is the locale. It makes no sense, to use `i18n` for that case when Rails itself is fundamentally broken. If Rails is that much broken to get the right localized error file, it or probably the server will serve `public/500.html`.

This was introduced in Rails 2.3.<sup>[1](https://github.com/mynewsdesk/devcorner/blob/master/_posts/2010-01-13-rails-i18n-and-404500-error-pages.md)</sup>

There is the solution to generate this static files with a `rake` task, before you deploy the app. [Have a look on this gist](https://github.com/mynewsdesk/devcorner/blob/master/_posts/2010-01-13-rails-i18n-and-404500-error-pages.md).