# Rails 5: How Do I Get My Error Pages in the Public Folder for Different Locales to Display Other than "en?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, error-handling, internationalization

When I was converting my Rails apps from 3.2.13 to Rails 4 I asked this question: [Rails 4 - Would Like To Do Custom Error Pages in Public Folder Using I18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569033/rails-4-would-like-to-do-custom-error-pages-in-public-folder-using-i18n). I found out that all I had to do was to create error files for each error code and locale. In my Rails 4 apps I had **404.en.html**, **404.fr.html**, **500.en.html** and **500.fr.html** in my public folder. They were working as expected.

I recently converted all of my Rails apps to Rails 5 but had not checked if this still worked until now. I redesigned one of my apps and upgraded to Rails 5.1.1. I recreated the error pages to my new website format. I'm trying to test my error pages in localhost before I deploy my changes to Heroku. I have the following temporary configuration in `/config/environments/development.rb` so I can see my error pages.

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

When I display my website in English and force an error the English error page **404.en.html** displays as expected. However when I display the French version of the page and force the same error the English error page displays, not the French error page **404.fr.html**. I verified several times that the text in the French error file is French, not English.

I've been searching on Stack Overflow and on the web in general but I'm not finding any information about how to do this for Rails 5. Just about all of it is for Rails 2, 3 or 4.

I decided to deploy to Heroku to see if maybe the issue was with my testing using localhost. Unfortunately I have the same problem.

I searched again and saw that in the Rails documentation they use rescue pages so I did a search on the Guides site for 5.0 and found the [following](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/action_view_overview.html#localized-views) about Localized views which briefly mentioned rescue files.

application_controller

```
before_action :set_locale

def default_url_options(options={}) 
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end

private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = (params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?) || cookies[:locale] || I18n.default_locale || 'en'
    cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale if cookies[:locale] != I18n.locale
  end
```

Here is my log where the locale is "es"

Started GET "/es" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-12 10:00:34 -0500
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"es"}
es

Here is how the English error page displays with locale es. When I click on any link on this page it displays the Spanish version of the website which I expect since the locale is es.

[image]

Here is the es error page in my public folder. You will see the text is in Spanish, not English.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to add internationalization to your error pages would be to add custom route to a controller and using yml file on `config/locales` to implement content in different languages.

First, define error routes and set up a controller to handle those routes

**config/routes.rb**

```
AwesomeApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # custom error routes
  match '/404' => 'errors#not_found', :via => :all
  match '/422' => 'errors#unprocessable_entity', :via => :all
  match '/500' => 'errors#internal_server_error', :via => :all

  ...
end
```

**app/controllers/errors_controller.rb**

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def internal_server_error
    render(:status => 500)
  end

  def not_found
    render(:status => 404)
  end

  def unprocessable_entity
    render(:status => 422)
  end
end
```

Then, add I18n definitions configuration for different languages.
For example, for English and French:

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  page_not_found: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."
```

**config/locales/fr.yml**

```
fr:
  page_not_found: "La page que vous recherchiez n'existe pas."
```

Then, use it on the corresponding view files of the `ErrorController`'s actions. Based on you `I18n.locale` value,  the views will be translated to desired language.

**app/views/errors/not_found.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="align-center">
      <h3><%= t('page_not_found') %></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a much cleaner way to setup error pages than maintaining different files for different errors on your public folder.

**UPDATE**

As suggested, this configuration is required on `config/application.rb` for this to work:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Comment: I did not want to go this route but because of other styling issues with the error pages I decided to implement this solution. I did everything here but it could not find my pages. I did a search and found another step I needed to do. Please update your answer to include adding config.exceptions_app = self.routes in config/application.rb to your answer and I will check it. Thanks!

Comment: updated the answer with the configuration update .. however the implementation works fine for my rails 5 app without that config

Comment: I may have something weird on my end. Maybe the two may not be connected. Thanks again! I have already changed several of my applications and plan to finish the rest of them today. Something happened when I upgraded to 5 where the error pages in the public folder only selected english. I'm glad to see that setting up custom error pages is a lot simpler than it was when I first learned Ruby on Rails years ago. Back then you had to create initiators which I did not want to bother with.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine on rails 5 (5.1.3). This is how myapp sets the locale in before_action

```
 def set_locale
   I18n.locale = params[:locale]
 end
```

And this request `http://localhost:3000/users/invalid_id?locale=en` renders en
[image: EN Error]

and `http://localhost:3000/users/invalid_id?locale=fr` renders french 
 [image: Fr Error]

My guess would be that you are not setting locale properly in `before_action`.

Do `Rails.logger.info I18n.locale` to log used locales in your `before_action` to debug it further.

Comment: I have added my locale logic in application_controller along with a couple of screenshots. The only time the locale does not work is with my error pages. I use route_translator, one of the recommended gems, to translate my routes by locale. I removed it and used the rails scope statement instead. I still have the problem.

Comment: I see what's happening, the url you are hitting doesn't exist and routes middleware throws the exception. In this case, `before_action` is not called hence `locale` doesn't get set. To make sure, this is what is actually happening, can you try a path which actually exists with that action having `raise` exception call.

Comment: If above test takes you to localized `500` error page, then you should find a way to set `I18n.locale` in a middleware before `routes` are executed. In that case `before_action` is too late.